# C++ chrono system time in milliseconds, time operations

Tags: c++, time, c++11, c++-chrono

I've got a small problem caused by insufficient documentation of C++11.

I'd like to obtain a time since epoch in milliseconds, or nanoseconds or seconds and then I will have to "cast" this value to another resolution.
I can do it using gettimeofday() but it will be to easy, so I tried to achieve it using std::chrono.

I tried:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = 
    std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

But I have no idea what is a resolution of obtained in this way time_point, and I don't know how to get this time as a simple unsigned long long, and I haven't any conception how to cast it to another resolution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::chrono and cout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889136/stdchrono-and-cout)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

You can do `now.time_since_epoch()` to get a duration representing the time since the epoch, with [the clock's resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8386128). To convert to milliseconds use [`duration_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast):

```
auto duration = now.time_since_epoch();
auto millis = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration).count();
```

Comment: +1.  More information here (it is nearly a tutorial):  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm

Comment: @Howard thanks! Now I have some place to point people to when they tell me they don't undersand `<chrono>`.

Comment: If you aren't including the shortcut headers:
auto duration = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes  Do you have some place to point people to when they tell you they don' understand how the C++ Standards Committee can so consistently produce insanely difficult application interfaces that require you to read 40 pages of documentation written by some guy on the internet to do what can be done in one line in a sensible language?

Comment: Or you could use `std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now())` to get a `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::milliseconds>`.