# c++ chrono duration_cast to milliseconds results in seconds

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I want to have the number of milliseconds since epoch. A popular solution looks like follows (one of the solutions of this question asked here [Get time since epoch in milliseconds, preferably using C++11 chrono](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16177295) )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    auto millitime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
        (std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    std::cout << millitime << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

compiling this with a call to `g++` like `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o timetest` results in the output

```
1372686001
```

which is equal to the number of **seconds** since epoch!

Is this a bug in the glibc? in g++? my mistake?

```
g++ (Debian 4.7.3-4) 4.7.3
ldd (Debian EGLIBC 2.17-6) 2.17
```

---

**Update:** it works when using the g++ 4.8. So it is a gcc bug?!

```
g++-4.8 (Debian 4.8.1-2) 4.8.1
```

Comment: Works fine here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=58cbeec8ffe15b00c4c5617e5c661e44-95b421f505320e75ab053309436f3288

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes do you use the same g++ and glibc versions?

Comment: I edited the link to include the output of `g++ -v` (it's 4.8.1). Meaning that if it was a bug, it was fixed.

Comment: The code works correctly under [GCC 4.7.2](http://ideone.com/s4VM4w)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes thanks for giving me the idea to use the g++ 4.8 `;)`. I will change g++ to point to version 4.8 per default - that should fix my problem. I don't know where yet, but maybe i should report this bug (as it seems rather certain now, that it is due to gcc v4.7.3)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what's happening is that you are compiling with GCC 4.7 but the run-time linker is using the `libstdc++.so` from a different GCC version, and they are configured with different precision for `std::chrono:system_clock`.  If you use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or suitable linker options to ensure you compile with GCC 4.7 **and** use its `libstdc++.so` then the results should be correct.

For example:

```
$ $HOME/gcc/4.7.1/bin/g++ -std=c++11 t.cc
$ ./a.out
1372693222
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/gcc/4.7.1/lib64 ./a.out
1372693225128
```

The difference happens because the call to `system_clock::now()` is in the `libstdc++.so` library so the result depends on which library is used at run-time, but the `duration_cast` conversion from that value to `milliseconds` is done by inline templates which are instantiated at compile-time. If the compile-time conversion is not consistent with the run-time call then the results are inconsistent.

For GCC 4.8.1 the `system_clock` implementation was improved to always use the `clock_gettime` system call if it's available, which was not the case for 4.7, so it consistently uses the high-precision clock no matter how GCC was configured, which probably explains why you don't see the problem with 4.8.1.

You should always ensure the right version of `libstdc++.so` is used at run-time.

Comment: brilliant. so far I never had to pay attention to this (kind of annoying that it is necessary to be honest)... I would have expected that this is enough cause for a new version number (clearly the different versions of the libc are incompatible!) but well... thank you for clearing it up for me

Comment: In their default configurations the libraries are compatible, one of your compilers must have been built with `--enable-libstdcxx-time` which alters the library ABI, in which case it's your job to avoid mixing incompatible libraries.