# std::chrono multiplies durations

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

Consider this example of code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main ( )
{
   using namespace std::chrono;

   system_clock::time_point s = system_clock::now();

   for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
      std::cout << duration_cast<duration<double>>(system_clock::now() - s).count() << "\n";
}
```

I expect this to print the elapsed time in seconds. But it actually prints time in thousands of second (the expected result multiplied by 0.001). Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**

Since `seconds` is equivalent to `duration<some-int-type>`, `duration_cast<seconds>` gives the same result.

I used gcc-4.7.3-r1

Comment: If you want seconds, you need to duration_cast<boost::chrono::seconds>

Comment: @DaveF: Only if you want to round to a whole number of seconds, since `seconds` is a convenience typedef for `duration<some_integer_type>`. `duration<double>` should also have a period of one second.

Comment: I tried it in VS2013 - works fine

Comment: How are you determining that it's printing milliseconds? If I compile and run that code, and watch the output, it increases by 1 each second as expected (that's with a slightly different version of GCC though).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405997/c-chrono-duration-cast-to-milliseconds-results-in-seconds) may help.

Comment: @maverik: that seems to be the right explanation. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[maverik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/644350/maverik) [guessed this right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039589/stdchrono-multiplies-durations#comment33414752_22039589): the problem was with [binary incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17408315/2315602) inside `std::chrono` - gcc-4.8 version of libstdc++ and gcc-4.7 did not agree on internal units of time.

Answer (score 2):

You program works as expected using both gcc 4.8.2 and VS2013. I think it might be a compiler bug in your old gcc 4.7

Answer (score -2):

You could use duration_cast < seconds > instead of duration_cast < duration < double > >

Comment: `seconds` is just a typedef for `duration<some_integer_type>`. `duration<double>` should also have a period of one second.

Comment: I've already tried. seconds seem to act exactly like duration<int, ratio<1>>, and duration_cast<milliseconds>(...) in fact gives me seconds.

Comment: I get different results when using Ideone with C++11 compiler between the two(seconds and duration<double>). Seconds only prints seconds(at least on that compiler). I cant test it on any other compiler atm however