# Get unixtime(0) in c++

Tags: c++, mysql, unix-timestamp

how can I get a unixtime epoch time in c++? not converting to current time, the starting point of unixtime, I need it to compare with field in database mysql. Someone can help me in that?

Comment: what do you mean by 'starting point of unixtime' ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is std::chrono epoch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799293/when-is-stdchrono-epoch)

Comment: What form do you want it in?  You already have it as a number (0).

Comment: Epoch time, 1970/1/1 00:00:0