# How to get the difference in milliseconds between the start time and now() in C++?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

My initial code was

```
using n_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
n_time::time_point c_time = n_time::now();
n_time::time_point start = n_time::now();


auto gyro::duration(){
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(c_time-start).count();
}
```

but then I realized that I wanted to find the milliseconds from a start argument to `now()`, and I wasn't sure if my initial code would give me that. So I tried

```
auto timeSince(n_time::time_point start) {
    n_time now = n_time::now();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now - start).count();
}
```

Is this how you would find the milliseconds after `start`? I heard there was a function called `time_since_epoch()` and I'm not sure if that would be better to use instead?

This clock is for a specific robot function I'm trying to write, so I need to make sure that the clock doesn't cause a conversion error:

```
void straight(int distance, int speed) { 
    int time = (distance / speed) * 1000; // milliseconds        
    while (timeSince() < time) {
        // code
    }
}
```

The `duration()` function does not give any errors in my function, but the `timeSince()` gives me conversion errors such as

> error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type
>   'std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point {aka
>   std::chrono::time_point >

Comment: You may consider using ``auto`` for the type, because your ``n_time now=n_time::now();`` is wrong type. Besides this, your initial method is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a close look at the C++ standard related to [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock), you will see that it contains a member type `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point` which is equivalent to `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>`.

Besides the above member type, `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` contains member function `now` which returns a `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>`, i.e. `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point`, representing the current value of the clock.

In your function, you have

```cpp
n_time now = n_time::now();
```

i.e. you are trying to assign `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point` to a variable of type `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` which does not sound clear, right? So, instead you should have

```cpp
n_time::time_point now = n_time::now();
```

Here is the full code:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using n_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

auto timeSince(n_time::time_point start) {
    n_time::time_point now = n_time::now();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now - start).count();
}

int main() {
    auto now = n_time::now() - std::chrono::seconds{3600};
    std::cout << timeSince(now) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the result is in milliseconds:

```
3600000
```

**UPDATE**

Here is how you can use the above working example in your case:

```cpp
void straight(int distance, int speed) {
    auto start = n_time::now();

    // some time has passed since this function has started

    int time = (distance / speed) * 1000; // milliseconds        
    while (timeSince(start) < time) {
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I want the `start` argument inside `timeSince()` to be when the function `straight(int distance, int speed)` starts, though. Do you know how I would be able to do this?

Comment: @ororodislikesphysicalexertion I updated my answer. Check it out and upvote and accept (that green tick below the votes) the answer if it helped you

Comment: all right, i tried that and got a conversion error saying "invalid operands of types 'void' and 'int' to binary 'operator<'
         while(timeSince(start) < time){" I thought the duration_cast would convert it to a different type?

Comment: @ororodislikesphysicalexertion the error shouldn't happen. Check [here](https://godbolt.org/z/_Xxr4A)

Answer (score 1):

> I heard there was a function called time_since_epoch() and I'm not sure if that would be better to use instead

Not really, see e.g. [When is std::chrono epoch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799293/when-is-stdchrono-epoch):

> There is a de-facto (unofficial) standard that std::chrono::system_clock::time_point has an epoch consistent with Unix Time. This is defined as the time duration that has elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, not counting leap seconds.

The error you see is generated by this line

```
n_time now = n_time::now();
```

Which should be

```
n_time::time_point now = n_time::now();
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Given `using n_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;`