# how can i get a difference between two Time interval's in micro and nano seconds using c++

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on a project, in that i need to check the time difference, between two times, am getting time difference in milliseconds , but now i want the time difference in micro and nano seconds to get  exact time difference

my code :

```
QDateTime oStartTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();  

// some operetions            //the difference is in micro and nano seconds differ 

QDateTime oEndTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();  
quint64 elapsed = oStartTime.daysTo(oEndTime)*1000*60*60*24 + oStartTime.time().msecsTo(oEndTime.time());
```

Above code will give me only milliseconds  difference in time . I also need the micro & nano seconds. Any suggestion how to get time with micro & nano seconds also?

Comment: std::chrono , is what you are looking. [See here for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089842/c-chrono-system-time-in-milliseconds-time-operations/31521226#31521226)

Comment: chrono is not supporting to my using QT4.3.2  version and  visual studio 2005  compiles , so is it possible to get  micro and nano seconds

Comment: try GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(LPFILETIME) , where FILETIME structure Contains a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond time-stamp.

Answer (score 2):

C++11 provides [chrono](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/) library to work with time. It has steady_clock specially designed to calculate time intervals. Also there's microseconds and nanoseconds instantiations of duration template class.

```
#include <chrono> // C++11
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{
    steady_clock::time_point tp1 = steady_clock::now();

    std::cout<<"some time to spend..."<<std::endl;
    steady_clock::time_point tp2 = steady_clock::now();

    nanoseconds spent_time = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(tp2 - tp1);
    std::cout<<"It took "<<spent_time.count()<<" nanoseconds."<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

stdout:

```
some time to spend...
It took 207960 nanoseconds.
```

Comment: am getting this type of error , seems it not supporting chrono

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'chrono': No such file or directory

Comment: @SrikanthTogara enable C++11 for your compliler to access `chrono`.

Answer (score 0):

QT provides [QElapsedTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qelapsedtimer.html) for getting time differences by using the system's high-resolution counter (see [clock types](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qelapsedtimer.html#ClockType-enum)).

Comment: but my QT is 4.3.2 version it does't support  QElapsedTimer , so will you please suggest me any alternate ways to get micro and nano seconds difference in time

Comment: You could use the native timer. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404277/porting-clock-gettime-to-windows).