# C++ Elapsed time is 0

Tags: c++, performance, winapi, time, rendering

The problem is that my program is so fast that it doesn't detect change in time, or GetTickCount(), how can i prevent this from happening?

Thank You

Comment: You can try something more precise if it's taking less than a millisecond. `QueryPerformanceCounter` would be a good start, or the new-ish `<chrono>` header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetTickCount has 5..15 millisecond precision, so "zero time difference" is a common problem.

If you need precision, use [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Are you printing the running time as an integer?  If you are doing division to get the elapsed time, cast the numerator or denominator as a float.

Answer (score 0):

Time how long `x` runs take and take an average.

Additionally you can use profiling for an accurate timing.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
void WINAPI GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(
  _Out_  LPFILETIME lpSystemTimeAsFileTime
);
```

instead. It has better resolution. In majority of cases this is really what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very handy class on CodeProject that wraps `QueryPerformanceCounter`, that I use often: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/475/The-CPerfTimer-timer-class

Answer (score -2):

Or you can try using rtdsc.
for details see here: http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~kazutomo/rdtsc.html
Snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "rdtsc.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  unsigned long long a,b;

  a = rdtsc();
  b = rdtsc();

  printf("%llu\n", b-a);
  return 0;
}
```

Or even chrono is good, but then it needs C++11 compliance (in part).
details: [std::chrono and cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889136/stdchrono-and-cout)

Comment: Bad idea - on multicore cpus.

Comment: Dear Friends, I know this is bad idea on multicore cpus, but it works to find out time elapsed in the case specified.