# Gtest framework for time

Tags: frameworks, googletest

How to print execution timing in seconds or minute in console for gtest framework? In console:

```
Gcctests.functionality test(456ms)
```

How to convert 456 ms into seconds?

Comment: You divide by 1000 to convert ms to sec. 456 / 1000 = 0.456 sec

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889136/stdchrono-and-cout