# high_resolution_clock error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’

Tags: c++

How to print the `high_resolution_clock` in C++?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock high_resolution_clock;

int main()
{
    std::cout << high_resolution_clock::now() << std::endl;
}
```

Building the above results in:

```
/home/greg/repositories/firstProject/main.cpp:27: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point {aka std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >}’)
     std::cout << high_resolution_clock::now() << std::endl;
     ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

and

```
/home/greg/repositories/firstProject/main.cpp:27: error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
     std::cout << high_resolution_clock::now() << std::endl;
                                             ^
```

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609915/stdvector-cannot-bind-stdostream-aka-stdbasic-ostreamchar-lvalue-t) I tried to iterate over the "container":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock high_resolution_clock;

int main()
{
    for(auto i: high_resolution_clock::now()){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However this resulted in even more errors. I also tried using `printf` and casting `high_resolution_clock::now()` to a `long long` with no success.

**Update:**

Trying another answer [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7889919/7629409) also yielded more errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock high_resolution_clock;

int main()
{
    auto i = high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << i.time_since_epoch() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::chrono and cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889136/stdchrono-and-cout)

Comment: @user1810087 I updated the post with the code which was suggested in the question you linked. The answer used a different library and the solution did not work in this example as it resulted in more compile errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every thing can be directly used with `cout`.

Have a look at the example at [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now/) on cplusplus.com

A simplified version as follows

```
// high_resolution_clock example
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    //Do sth Here

    auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);

    std::cout << "It took me " << time_span.count() << " seconds.";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I think this can solve your problem.

Comment: From the page you link it says that the function `now()` "Returns the current time_point in the frame of the high_resolution_clock.". How can this time be printed without doing any computation on it first?

Comment: You can then use the high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count(), I think. (the time_point type has a member function called count) Sorry for the previous mistake

Comment: If the answer in my code works, you can simply change the t2 - t1 into t2 and it should still work. But the  high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count() works fine for my compiler.

Comment: Will accept now that you added `.time_since_epoch()` since it works :)

Answer (score 8):

I really appreciate the recommendation in [Passer By's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46362858/576911), however I'm afraid it isn't quite correct.  [My date library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) provides I/O for `system_clock`, but not `high_resolution_clock`.  However [Passer By's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46362858/576911) happens to work with gcc because with that tool set `high_resolution_clock` is a type alias for `system_clock`.

I'm using clang, and with this toolset `high_resolution_clock` is a type alias for `steady_clock` (and ditto on Visual Studio). On these platforms [Passer By's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46362858/576911) will cause a compile-time error which complains that there is no `operator<<` found.

To understand why this is, it is important to understand the distinction between `system_clock` and `steady_clock`:

`system_clock` is like a watch (the thing on your wrist before smart phones took over the planet).  It can tell you the time of day.  And because no clock keeps perfect time, it sometimes asks another clock what time it is and makes tiny adjustments to itself to stay accurate.

`steady_clock` is like a stopwatch.  It is great for timing a runner on a lap, or timing your function.  It never adjusts itself, but strives to mark one second per second as best it can.  But it has no idea what the time of day is, or even what day of the year.

`high_resolution_clock` also has no relationship to any human calendar or time system, and is allowed to be a `typedef` to either `system_clock` or `steady_clock`.  And in practice, it always is a `typedef` to one of these clocks.  Now that you know what `system_clock` and `steady_clock` are, just use one of those, and your code will be more portable.

[My library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) provides I/O for `system_clock`, as its main purpose is to extend `<chrono>` into the realm of calendars.

You *can* use [my library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) to stream out `chrono::duration`s.  So if you really wanted to, you can get the `duration` out of a `high_resolution_clock` and stream that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include "date.h"

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock high_resolution_clock;

using date::operator<<;

int main()
{
    std::cout << high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch() << std::endl;
}
```

This just output for me:

```
2553634286064557ns
```

On my platform this means my computer has been booted up for about that many nanoseconds.  Or if you prefer something more readable:

```
    std::cout << date::format("%T\n", high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
```

which just output:

```
709:32:51.552928058
```

My computer has been booted for about 709 hours and 32 minutes.

For a video tutorial of `<chrono>` which includes the distinction between `system_clock` and `steady_clock`, and a lot more, see:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Comment: Thank you for the amazing answer, one question I have is when `system_clock` makes adjustments, does it ever "go back in time" or does it try to slow down instead it is ahead? That is, are sequential `system_clock`s strictly increasing in value?

Comment: @GNettlefold: All of the `<chrono>` clocks have a `static constexpr bool` value called `is_steady` which addresses your question.  If `is_steady` is `true`, that means that the clock never goes backwards in time, and has a "close" approximation to a constant tick rate.  For `system_clock`, the value of `is_steady` is unspecified.  So if false on your platform, it might not be monotonic.  `steady_clock::is_steady` is required to be true.

Answer (score 2):

Use Howard Hinnant's [date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), which is being proposed for standardization.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include "date.h"

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock high_resolution_clock;

using date::operator<<;

int main()
{
    std::cout << high_resolution_clock::now() << std::endl;  // works!!
}
```

[Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gJ1wl464yzjszETu)

Fun fact: Howard Hinnant is one of the authors of `chrono` and considers them not able to be outputted directly an oversight/defect

EDIT: Its not portable to output `high_resolution_clock::time_point`, check out [Howard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46365721/4832499) for details

Comment: Thank you for this. Do you mind briefly explaining how the above code works? (In case I encounter a similar type problem in the future)

Comment: If I understand it correctly, `<<` is a function inside the "date.h" header file and you use that instead of the standard operator for the `high_resolution_clock` datatype?

Comment: @GNettlefold `ostream` doesn't have an `operator<<` for the `chrono` stuff, `date.h` have them defined. To format them, `date.h` has very good support for them, check the link, there should be some tutorials.